# SQL Server Join with Wildcard and stop on first match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TABLE1
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TABLE2

    CREATE TABLE #TABLE1
    (
        CODE_NAME_T1 NVARCHAR(20)
    )

    CREATE TABLE #TABLE2
    (
        CODE_NAME_T2 NVARCHAR(20)
    )

    INSERT INTO #TABLE1(CODE_NAME_T1)
    VALUES             ('BBX123')
                      ,('BC/230')
                      ,('1AC030')
                      ,('BB01BC')           

    INSERT INTO #TABLE2(CODE_NAME_T2)
    VALUES             ('BB')
                      ,('BC')

    SELECT T1.CODE_NAME_T1, T2.CODE_NAME_T2
    FROM #TABLE1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.CODE_NAME_T1 LIKE '%' + T2.CODE_NAME_T2 + '%'

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TABLE1
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TABLE2
```

### RESULT

```
CODE_NAME_T1   |    CODE_NAME_T2
---------------|-----------------
BBX123         |     BB
BC/230         |     BC
1AC030         |     NULL
BB01BC         |     BB
BB01BC         |     BC
```

Hi, in above code I am using wildcard in join.  The problem I am facing that in result "BB01BC" row is appearing twice as it contains both "BB" and "BC" characters.  Is there way that it only appears once.  So if "BB" is matched in "BB01BC" then it should not look for "BC" in it?  Basically only doing one match/lookup and not doing more match/lookup?

Comment: Do you not care about the data in the `CODE_NAME_T2` column at all?  If the data doesn't matter, you can remove the column from the results and do a `SELECT DISTINCT`.  If you *do* care about the values, what one should it pick as the "first" value?  Are you intending for the value returned to always be *alphabetically* the first matching result?

Comment: I need both columns and want only the first match.  Don't has to be alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT T1.CODE_NAME_T1, T2.CODE_NAME_T2
FROM #TABLE1 T1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 t2.*
      FROM #TABLE2 T2
      WHERE T1.CODE_NAME_T1 LIKE '%' + T2.CODE_NAME_T2 + '%'
     ) T2;
```

Note:  You almost always want an `ORDER BY` when using `TOP`.  You don't seem particularly interested in *which* row from `T2` matches, you just want one of them.  If you have a particular priority, then add `ORDER BY` for prioritization.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  This what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your situation:
`SELECT T1.CODE_NAME_T1, (SELECT TOP 1 T2.CODE_NAME_T2 from #TABLE2 T2 where T1.CODE_NAME_T1 LIKE '%' || T2.CODE_NAME_T2 || '%')
    FROM #TABLE1 T1`